# ajax not sending data to specified page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been following a tutorial and the person who does it provide the code for you to use, so ive tried using the code and going through it line by line but as i hardly know anything about ajax, i cant seem to understand why it is not passing data through to the page that is specified,and since the data isnt being passed through the process of mysqli queries and all other things, they wont begin to happen as the data isnt being passed over.

The data is part of a form and it is to check usernames against the database to check availability, so the code for the data in the form is ...

```
<form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
<div>Username: </div>
<input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
<span id="unamestatus"></span>
<div>Email Address:</div>
<input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">...
```

And so on... the js provided is ..

```
function restrict(elem){
  var tf = _(elem);
  var rx = new RegExp;
  if(elem == "email"){
  rx = /[' "]/gi;
  } else if(elem == "username"){
  rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
  }
  tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
_(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
var u = _("username").value;
if(u != ""){
_("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signupfunc.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
       _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
   }
    }
    ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
}
```

So as far as i understand, **var u= _("username").value** is the value of the input with the id=username, and if username is not blank then it firstly brings up the *checking...* before starting the var that is called ajax, it begins the process of POSTing to the page, *signupfunc.php*, then im not exactly sure the next bit but i think it means something like if something returns from the *var ajax* then it puts the response return in the **unamestatus** div ?? then the last bit does as it says? the var ajax sends the value of usernamecheck as the username... but it is not sending the data to the specified page ... can someone point out what im doing wrong advise how to solve this problem ??

and just incase it is needed here is the code that is on the specified page signupfunc.php that is related to the code above..

```
//Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){

    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
   echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
   exit();
}
if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
   echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
   exit();
}
 if ($uname_check < 1) {
   echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
   exit();
    } else {
   echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
   exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to watch the request / response in your browser's console. Any errors in the request will show up there and allow you to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: there doesnt seem to be any errors that i can see, but ill be honest, im not exactly sure what id be looking for

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try change you code with below jquery ajax code :

```
function checkusername(){
var u = _("username").value;
if(u != ""){
_("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';

    $.ajax({
        url : "signupfunc.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : "usernamecheck="+u,
        dataType : 'text',
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            alert(data);
        }
   })
}
```

Comment: ok using this code, i get the alert that pops up, i get **<h1> username: </h1>**  so the username data doesnt get passed still :S

Comment: u can using tag.. that just example... u can change alert(data) to this document.getElementById('unamestatus').innerHTML = data; or u can use jquery like this   $('#unamestatus').html(data)